# When should I declare header file?

Tags: header, petalinux

I have a code workspace with .cpp and .h files which comprises of couple of layers:

```
`main.cc
   user.cpp   [global functions]
   user.h
        api.cpp
        api.h`
```

I have a global user function in user.cpp that I need to call in api.cpp.
I am trying to understand in what circumstances I should contain this line:
`#include "user.h"`
in api.cpp

1. Can source contain header of level above him in the hierarchy?
2. If the functions in user.cpp are global, does the compiler should detect it automatically?

I am working in Vitis platform. I found out that if i choose bare metal env. it detect it automatically. When I am using Linux env. it doesn't (unless i contain the header file)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say you should almost always include the header file for the function you want to call.  Makes things more explicit and understandable.